# Debian won't reconnect ethernet after physical disconnection

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet

> Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
   source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback


    allow-hotplug eno1
    iface eno1 inet static
         address 192.168.1.249
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         network 192.168.1.0
         gateway 192.168.1.1
         dns 192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Why the event of disconnection and reconnection of the ethernet port is not detected?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `auto eno1` right before `iface eno1 inet static`.

Comment: Why should the OP add this? What will it achieve? Please see [answer] and take our [tour] to learn how to improve your answer.